# $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\sqrt{1 + \frac{k}{n^2}} - 1)$ Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

> Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = \frac{1}{4}$ 
>   $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{k}{n^2}} - 1\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{k}{n^2}} - 1\right) < \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2n^2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{4n^2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{4} \:\:\text{as}\:\: n \rightarrow \infty$$

Can anyone give me a hint on how i should continue?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the function $\sqrt{1+x}$ is bounded below by the second order Taylor approximation.

Comment: Heuristically,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrack n\int_{1/n}^{1}\left(\sqrt{1 + {x \over n}} - 1\right)\,{\rm d}x\right\rbrack = {1 \over 4}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac k{n^2}}-1=\frac{\frac{k}{n^2}}{\sqrt{1+\frac k{n^2}}+1}
$$
where the denominator is bounded by
$$
2<\sqrt{1+\frac k{n^2}}+1\le\sqrt{1+\frac 1{n}}+1<2+\frac1{2n}
$$